# Tensorflow.js - how to create a model for a simple sum

Tags: tensorflow, configuration, layer, tensorflow.js

I am starting studies with tensoflow.js. I've seen and recreated the prediction example for a linear function; where you initially have:

```
async function learnLinear(){
   model = tf.sequential();
   // uma camada e um nó
   model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));
   // 
   model.compile({
      loss: 'meanSquaredError', //funcao de perda: erro quadratico médio p/ funcoes lineares
      optimizer: 'sgd' // descida de gradiente estocástica - metodologia para o aprendizado
      });
   
   // abaixo valores x,y nos parametros e o segundo é o formato 6 linhas 1 coluna
   const xs = tf.tensor2d([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],[6, 1]); 
   const ys = tf.tensor2d([-3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7], [6, 1]);

   // treinar o modelo em um número fixo de iterações (épocas)
   await model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 900}); // 900 iterações
   ...
```

Now I want to implement a simple sum, as suggested in the table below.

[image: sum]

But I was unable to create a template configuration for this (how the tensors, layers and training would look). Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a simple linear regression, like in your example. Results will be terrible with that amount of data, so don't expect to replace your calculator with that just yet.

Just setup your x1 and x2 tensor, and have the input of your model accept 2 inputs.

```js
// Define a model for linear regression.
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [2]}));

// Prepare the model for training: Specify the loss and the optimizer.
model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});

// Generate some synthetic data for training.
const x1 = tf.tensor2d([1, 1, 2, 1, 3], [5, 1]);
const x2 = tf.tensor2d([0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [5, 1]);
// we concat x1 and x2 to get an input of the shape [5,2]
// "Tensor [[1, 0],
//          [1, 1],
//          [2, 1],
//          [1, 1],
//          [3, 1]]"
const xs = tf.concat([x1,x2],1)
// The labels is just the sum of x1+x2
// "Tensor [[1],[2],[3],[2],[4]]"
const ys = tf.add(x1,x2)

// Train the model using the data.
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=1000).then(() => {
  // Try one prediction. 
  // The result will be pretty bad because 
  // there is not much data
  model.predict(tf.tensor2d([0, 1], [1, 2])).print();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your return. And, yes, the idea is just to understand more basic concepts for now, that allow me the next steps (with the calculator on my side!).